# How to convert a string into condition in the IF statement

Tags: php

Let say I have a string stored in the $condition variable:

```
$condition = '2 == 2'; // returns TRUE
```

or

```
$condition = 'my_own_function()'; // which also returns TRUE
```

How can I convert them into a condition in an IF statement? Say:

```
if (some_magic_converter_function($condition)){
    // execute something
}
```

it will be the same as if I execute

```
if (my_own_function()){
    // execute something
}
```

Is there any other ways I can **safely** evaluate the string into a condition of an IF statement? How?

Comment: `eval`, but no, please don't.

Comment: @JonStirling ouch. that's evil.

Comment: Love your passive aggresive comments here and there @JonStirling ;)

Comment: @FarizLuqman What are you trying to do? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: The basic rule of thumb: If you need to use `eval()`, you're doing something **very very wrong**.

Comment: @Timmetje I'm trying very hard not to use eval() at all cost :)

Comment: @FarizLuqman That is a good approach :P

Comment: @Styphon I'm very curious right now. I just can't hold myself from asking this question after hours of research on Dr.Google. :p

Comment: Ok ok I'll answer, but pretty please don't use it ! :)

Comment: @FarizLuqman OK, so are you just asking this in a theoretical instance, or do you have an actual problem in a program you're trying to solve? This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @Styphon I'm trying to do a very simple "templating" language, I have achieved success in a for loop, and accessing variable, but not in the "IF" statement :(

Comment: @FarizLuqman OK, I get what you're trying to do. Have you had a look at Blade or Twig to see how they do it? One of the best ways to learn new, complicated things like this is to reverse engineer an existing solution and then rewriting it your own way.

Comment: @Styphon I understand. I will answer my own question here once I found the solution :) thanks!

Comment: @Styphon I have written my own condition parser here, take a look https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/PVFKQCLEHS

Comment: @Styphon please see my answer, may it help people like me **grin** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that we can fully make use of preg_match to accomplish the above task:

```
/**
 * Function parse_condition
 * @param string $condition
 * @return bool
 */
function parse_condition($condition){
    // match {a} {condition} {b}
    preg_match('/.*(.*?)\s(.*?)\s(.*?)/sU', $condition, $condition_matches);

    // condition_matches[1] will be a, remove $, () and leading/tailing spaces
    $a = trim(str_replace(array('$','()'),'',$condition_matches[1]));

    // condition_matches[2] will be the operator
    $operator = $condition_matches[2];

    // condition_matches[3] will be b, remove $, () and leading/tailing spaces
    $b = trim(str_replace(array('$','()'),'',$condition_matches[3]));


    // It is advisable to pass variables into array or a "hive"
    // but in this example, let's just use global

    // Make variable's variable $$a accessible
    global $$a;
    // And for $$b too
    global $$b;

    $cmp1 = isset($$a)?($$a):($a);

    $cmp2 = isset($$b)?($$b):($b);

    switch($operator){
        case '==':
            return($cmp1 == $cmp2);
            break;
        case '!=':
            return($cmp1 != $cmp2);
            break;
        case '===':
            return($cmp1 === $cmp2);
            break;
        case '!==':
            return($cmp1 !== $cmp2);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }   
}
```

so I can use it like this:

```
// TESTCASES
$var_a = 100;
$var_b = 100;
$var_c = 110;
$var_d = (double) 100;


if(parse_condition('$var_a == $var_b')){ // TRUE
    echo 'Yeah I am Good!' . PHP_EOL;
}

if(parse_condition('$var_a != $var_c')){ // TRUE
    echo 'Good for this one too!' . PHP_EOL;
}

if(parse_condition('$var_b == $var_c')){ // FALSE
    echo 'Yeah I am Good!' . PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo 'But I am not with this one :(' . PHP_EOL;
}

if(parse_condition('$var_a != 110')){ // TRUE
    echo 'I can compare values too' . PHP_EOL;
}

if(parse_condition('$var_a === $var_d')){ // FALSE
    //
}else{
    echo 'Or even tell the difference between data types' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule of thumb: If you need to use `eval()`, you're doing something **very very wrong**.

But for entertainment purposes:

```
$condition = "return 2==2;";
$test = eval($condition);
if ($test) {
    echo 'Oh Noes';
}

function my_own_function()
{
    return true;
}
$condition = 'return my_own_function();';
$test = eval($condition);
if ($test) {
    echo "More Noes";
}
```

Comment: Okay I won't use it **sigh**